# Jquery Accordion Form with validation doesn't stop where I want it to

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify the jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/ buy a house demo. It is just exactly what I need as a model for my accordion form. The only problem is that the 3rd panel header I have made goes up under the second panel and the second panel stops at the first like I want. How do I keep the third panel header from going under the second panel header? I’ve tried everything but I don’t know how to change the 0,1 and 2 values that seem to control where they stop. I’m new at this and any help is appreciated. 2 stops in the same place 1 stops.

```
// these buttons all run the validation, overridden by specific targets above
$(".open2").click(function() {
    if (v.form()) {
        accordion.accordion("activate", 2);
        current = 2;
     }
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    if (v.form()) {
        accordion.accordion("activate", 1);
        current = 1;
     }
});

$(".open0").click(function() {
    if (v.form()) {
        accordion.accordion("activate", 0);
        current = 0;
    }
});
```